# Made typo, Python function still works. Why?

Tags: python, list, sudoku, transpose

I've been learning programming and Python for about a month now using Udacity. For one of the questions we are supposed to write a function that checks if a sudoku list passed in is valid.

In the for loop below, I wanted to iterate through `row` and `col` at the same time with both the original and transposed list using `zip()` but mistakenly left in `row` in the second half of my `or` statement. I ran it and to my surprise, it still continued to return a correct answer.

```
def check_sudoku(array):  
    is_sudoku = True
    reference = range(1, len(array) + 1)
    transposed = zip(array)

    for row, col in zip(array, transposed):
        if sorted(row) != reference or sorted(row) != reference:
            is_sudoku = False
            break
    return is_sudoku
```

My guess is it's because I defined `is_sudoku = True` by default, and I'm comparing `rows` with a reference list so it catches invalid values even if my transpose didn't work. When I replaced the second `row` with `col` though, it broke.

My question is, is my guess right? If not, why does this code work and how could I better write this?

Thanks! (Pasted on codepad as well if you want to see what lists I passed in - http://codepad.org/IXDlZuUu)

Comment: I think you need to change `zip(array)` into `zip(*array)` to make it work.

Comment: nvm, it's apparently only relevant for py3k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the correct value was False, then your function works because at some point `sorted(row) != reference`.  As for rewriting it, I'd think something like this would be more clear:

```
def check_sudoku(array):  
    reference = range(1, len(array) + 1)
    transposed = zip(array)
    for row, col in zip(array, transposed):
        if sorted(row) != reference or sorted(row) != reference:
            return False
    return True
```

Additionally, it's pretty hard for me to see why you do `transposed = zip(array)` and then `zip(array, transposed)`.  As far as I can tell that just takes a list like `[1, 2, 3]` and turns it into `[(1, (1,)), (2, (2,)), (3, (3,))]`.

If you are looking to iterate through the rows and columns, here's one method that works.

```
>>> rows = incorrect
>>> cols = [[row[i] for i in range(len(rows[0]))] for row in rows]
>>> cols = [[row[i] for row in rows] for i in range(len(row))]
>>> cols
[[4, 6, 3, 9, 7, 8, 1, 5, 2], [1, 5, 9, 6, 3, 2, 4, 8, 7], [2, 8, 7, 4, 5, 1, 9, 3, 6], [3, 9, 5, 2, 1, 7, 6, 4, 8], [6, 4, 2, 3, 8, 9, 5, 7, 1], [7, 1, 8, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2, 9], [8, 3,
 1, 7, 6, 4, 2, 9, 5], [5, 2, 6, 8, 9, 3, 7, 1, 4], [1, 7, 4, 1, 2, 5, 8, 6, 3]]
>>> rows
[[4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 1], [6, 5, 8, 9, 4, 1, 3, 2, 7], [3, 9, 7, 5, 2, 8, 1, 6, 4], [9, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 1], [7, 3, 5, 1, 8, 4, 6, 9, 2], [8, 2, 1, 7, 9, 6, 4, 3, 5], [1, 4,
 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 7, 8], [5, 8, 3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 1, 6], [2, 7, 6, 8, 1, 9, 5, 4, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `zip(array, transposed)` after consulting the Python documentation for looping over 2 lists at the same time (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques). My goal was to both check the rows and columns of the array, and I thought `transposed` would let me iterate through the list with just one `if` statement.

Comment: @poteto Well given that checking rows and checking columns are two different things, I don't think it makes a lot of sense to zip and compare like that.  However, you could do `for row, col in zip(rows, cols):` using rows and cols from my example if you wanted to iterate over 1 row and 1 column at a time.  Also it's worth noting that right now you are not verifying that the sudoku is valid, just that the numbers 1-9 are in each row and column.

Comment: Thanks for the example! If every row and column contains 1-9 (no repetition or out of range numbers) then wouldn't the Sudoku be valid by definition? I can't think of a case where an invalid Sudoku would pass this test.

Comment: You aren't checking whether each 3x3 box contains the numbers 1-9.

Comment: Ah yes I completely overlooked that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @poteto not a problem, if I have solved your issue then I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer: it's a pretty standard response if your problem is solved.  I noticed that you are new so I though I would say something ;)